# When date is Null return another value? - DB2 database

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to write a query which returns a specific date when the result is null.

My attempt:

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(t1.COLUMN_NAME) is null THEN '9999-12-31'
```

I am getting the error  DB2 SQL Error:

> SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=AS;END OVER CONCAT || / - + AT
>   * YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS DAY DAYS

Why is this?

Comment: Show the complete statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the keyword `end`

this:

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(t1.COLUMN_NAME) is null THEN '9999-12-31'
```

should be this:

```
CASE WHEN TRIM(t1.COLUMN_NAME) is null THEN '9999-12-31' else t1.column_name end
```

Also, you don't need the trim function.  `trim(null)` is `null`.  Plus, this assumes your field is char or varchar.  If it's a date, you can't use `trim`.  Also, make sure your default value is a valid date in db2.

Comment: Which would return null in all cases where `t1.COLUMN_NAME` is _not_ null; not sure that was the goal.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `trim()` if you are checking for `NULL` values.  So, consider something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.COLUMN_NAME, '9999-12-31')
```

Your question is actually *why* you are getting that error.  Well, basically it is listing some possible tokens that can appear between the '9999-12-31' and whatever comes next.  One of these is `END` (although it is missing `ELSE` as a possibility).